# Why does Google Analytics match this URL as a Funnel Step?

Tags: web, google-analytics

I have a Goal and a Funnel with 5 steps defined. The Destination URL is set to "Equals to". Then in my Funnel I have something similar to:

/ABCModules/Stuff/page1.aspx

/ABCModules/Stuff/page2.aspx

/ABCModules/Stuff/page3.aspx

/ABCModules/Stuff/page4.aspx

/ABCModules/Stuff/page5.aspx

When I click through those pages on my website, the Goal is met as expected.

But now let us say I do something goofy like this to one of the pages to (attempt to) cause it to fail the Goal:

/ABCXXXXXXXXModules/Stuff/page2.aspx

(and I save...)

When I click through the pages on my website again, this time I expect the Goal to NOT be met because page2 does NOT meet the "Equals to" requirement due to the X's. However, it DOES trigger the Goal (not what I expected). What is going on? Please help me understand how the matching works.

Thank you!!

UPDATE:
Not sure if important info or not, but I am looking under the Real Time Conversions to see my Goals match. I am starting to suspect a bug in Google Analytics Real Time because of the following behavior.

I have a simple 3 step Funnel. The first step is required. However, I go to go my web site, never do the first step, and go to the final step and it matches the goal in the Real Time Conversions. WTH?!?! I am not understanding something correctly probably. please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour (even if it does not make a lt of sense). The funnel steps only affect the funnel visualization, not completed goals.

See the f[ollowing example from the documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2976313?hl=en) which (I think) covers our question:

> For example, let's say your funnel is defined as /step1 > /step2 >
>   /step3 > goal, and a user navigates from /step2 to goal, skipping
>   /step1 and /step3. In the Funnel Visualization report, you'd see an
>   entrance to /step 2, a continuation to /step 3, and a continuation to
>   goal.